# What is wrong with print (2 & 2) >> 1?

Tags: function, perl, bit-manipulation, expression

I am just wondering what happens with that piece of code.
Why the result is incorrect only when printed directly, why is the newline ignored?

```perl
user@host_09:22 AM: perl
print 2 >> 1, "\n";
print 2 & 2, "\n";
print (2 & 2) >> 1, "\n";
1
2
2user@host_09:22 AM: perl
$a = (2 & 2) >> 1;
print "$a\n";
1
```

Comment: Turn on warnings (`perl -w`)

Comment: Just for completeness: for the general case you should turn on warnings with the warnings module (`use warnings;` or `-Mwarnings`), not `-w`, as `-w` also can affect modules you use that you have no control over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you print it with warnings it becomes clear(er)

```
perl -we'print (2 & 2), "\n"'
```

says

```
print (...) interpreted as function at -e line 1.
Useless use of a constant ("\n") in void context at -e line 1.
```

It works out `print (2&2)` as a function call to `print`<sup>†</sup> and duly prints 2 (no newline!), and then it keeps evaluating the [comma operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator), with `"\n"` in void context next, which it also warns us about.

With `>> 1` also there, the return `1` of `print (2&2)` (for success) is bit shifted to `0`, which disappears into the void, and we get
another "*Useless use of ... in void context*."

One fix is to add a `+` since what follows it must be an expression

```
perl -we'print +(2 & 2) >> 1, "\n"'
```

Or, make a proper call to `print`, with parenthesis around the whole thing

```
perl -we'print((2 & 2) >> 1, "\n")'
```

Both print a line with `1`.

This is mentioned in [print](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html), and more fully documented in [Terms and List operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Terms-and-List-Operators-(Leftward)) and in [Symbolic Unary operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators), both in [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html). For another, related, example see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60312486/4653379).

---

<sup>†</sup> It also warns about it as it is likely an error -- with a space before parens; no space, no warning.

Comment: Or you could add parenthesis around the parameters, too, of course: `print((2 & 2) >> 1, "\n");`

Comment: @DavidKrupička Welcome :) Let me know if questions come up

Answer (score 6):

Perl interprets the parentheses as function arguments marker, as you can verify with

```
perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e 'print (2 & 2) >> 1'
```

Output:

```
(print(2) >> 1);
```

The canonical way is to precede the left parenthesis with a `+`:

```
print +(2 & 2) >> 1
```

Comment: Well, it's more idiomatic to add the omitted parens. But yeah, the idiomatic way of leaving them off is to use a unary `+`.

Comment: It's worth noting that unary `+` work with any kind of values, not just numbers. It literally has no effect on the value passed to it.

Comment: I like the -MO=Deparse suggestion, but if you don't mind, I marked zdim's post as the answer, because it is slightly more detailed.