# "isn't numeric" error in "sort" after "uniq"

Tags: perl, sorting, uniq

```
use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';
print join ", ", sort uniq ("b", "a", "a");
```

results in *Argument "a" isn't numeric in sort at ...*

```
print join ", ", uniq sort ("b", "a", "a");
```

works as expected.

```
print join ", ", sort {$a cmp $b} uniq ("b", "a", "a");
```

works too - but what is the problem with the first example?

Comment: My guess is that the `sort uniq ...` is interpreted as the [`sort SUBNAME LIST`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) syntax where `SUBNAME` is `uniq` instead of the intended `sort LIST` syntax. You can achieve the latter using `sort @{[uniq ("b", "a", "a")]}`

Comment: @HåkonHægland Why isn't  `sort (uniq @list)` parsed as `sort LIST` syntax when `sort ("a","b","c")` is?  Is this just a strange quirk of the Perl parser?

Comment: @JimGarrison In `sort (uniq @ary)` there is no reason for the interpreter to see that `uniq` is anything other than a bareword in that list (and is thus out of place). Thus `sort (uniq(@ary));` works

Comment: @Jim Garrison, `sort`'s syntax is what's quirky. Specifically, it's very ambigous, so Perl needs to perform all kinds of guesses.

Comment: Here's something insane: while `sort(uniq(@ary))` works, `sort(uniq (@ary))` does not. The only difference is the space I added between `uniq` and `(@ary)`. I always thought whitespace was not semantically significant!

Comment: @joanis  It's the extra parens that don't count so `(word (@ary))` is no different from `(word @ary)`.  It's a good point though, that li'l space does count here (under `sort`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That code falls under the [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) invocation of

> **sort SUBNAME LIST**
>
> ...
>    If SUBNAME is specified, it gives the name of a subroutine that returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than 0 , depending on how the elements of the list are to be ordered.

The `uniq` in the first example is taken as a bareword that specifies the name of the sub to use for sorting and `qw(b a a)` is the list to sort -- you aren't `uniq`-ing the list (so to speak) but are using `uniq` as a sorting function for that list.

The error message comes as a sorting function needs to return a number and `uniq` returns strings.

You've discovered one way to make it work, and can also use the unary `+`

```
say for sort +uniq(@ary);    # or: say for sort + uniq @ary;
```

since what follows `+` is treated as *an expression*, so `sort` gets the evaluated list. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56556921/4653379)  and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57784446/4653379) for discussion of such uses of the unary `+`.

Or use parens through and through

```
say for sort (uniq(@ary));
```

Here the inner pair is also necessary since with `sort (uniq @ary)` the `uniq` is interpreted as a bareword in that list, thus out of place. Note that `sort (uniq (@ary))` won't work since extra parens don't matter and we again have a bareword; so that space matters here!

This trickiness is due to `sort`'s flexible (ambiguous) interface, taking a `LIST` *optionally* preceded by a bareword, which need be a sub name.  It ends up relying on the interpreter to sort out some of that and then we have to be precise.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, thank you (just posted a comment with that but forgot it here), added to answer