# Perl sort corrupts bsd_glob results

Tags: perl, glob

This is really simple case:

```
use feature qw/say/;
use File::Glob qw/bsd_glob/;

# got many wav files
say foreach bsd_glob "*.wav";

# got "*.wav" as only result
say foreach sort bsd_glob "*.wav";
say foreach sort bsd_glob("*.wav");
```

Why `sort` keyword has affect on `bsd_glob` funtion, and make it behaves like not find the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use unintentionally using the

```
sort SUBNAME LIST
```

syntax, telling `sort` to use `bsd_glob` as the compare function.

You could explicitly specify the compare function

```
sort { $a cmp $b } bsd_glob "*.wav"
```

You could refrain from omitting the parens around the operands and arguments.

```
 sort(bsd_glob(*.wav"))
```

Omitting parens around the operands and arguments can lead to weird errors.

Answer (score 3):

When you say

```
sort bsd_glob $pattern;
```

then the `bsd_glob` is used as a sorting (comparison) function, with the `$pattern` tnen being the list to sort (parens used around the pattern notwithstanding).

The quickest workaround is

```
sort +bsd_glob $pattern;
```

where the unary `+` makes the following (`bsd_glob`) be treated as an expression, in which case it cannot be a sorting function. Then the default `{ $a cmp $b }` sorting is used, as intended.

Or, use another set of parens around the list to be sorted `(bsd_glob(...))`.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57445059/4653379) for details, and the links in it.