# Get the first item of the list returned by function

Tags: perl

A simple simulation of the problem:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub uniq
{
  my %seen;
  grep !$seen{$_}++, @_;
}

my @a = (1, 2, 3, 1, 2);

print shift @{uniq(@a)};
```

> Can't use string ("3") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use

Comment: What do you actrually do with that first item ... assign it to a variable, or really print it (or pass it to a function or such) ?

Comment: I want to avoid assigning it to a dummy/temporary variable. I want to use it as a parameter in another function.

Comment: OK.  Then do you need to actually remove it from the return list as well (is the `shift` necessary)?  What with the rest, keep it or not?

Comment: I need just the 1st item, rest is useless to me. But the code above is not exactly what I have – I use a different function (which **I cannot modify**) that at the end uses the `uniq` before it returns it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Need to impose a list context on the function call, and then pick the first element from the list.

The `print`, or any other subroutine call, already supplies a list context. Then one way to extract an element from a returned *list*

```
print +( func(@ary) )[0];
```

This disregards the rest of the list.

That `+` is necessary (try without it), unless we equip [print](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print) itself with parentheses around all its arguments, that is

```
print( (func(@ary))[0] );
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56556921/4653379) and/or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60312486/4653379) for examples and docs about the need for that `+` or `()`.

Comment: Technically, `(uniq @a)[0]` should be identical to `$a[0]`, for any possible values of `@a`. Perhaps it will not differ between `undef` and `''` (empty string).

Comment: @TLP What they posted is just an example, their real function does more work.  (See their comment.) Imagine `f(qw(a b c)) -> 3,4,5,6`.  (Or, rather, what I imagine is a library  returning a list but they only need the first value.  And they can't touch library's code.)

Comment: Yes, I see it now. I was confused by the OP posting a self-made function included in the question, rather than a library function elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

If `uniq` returned an array reference, then `@{uniq(...)}` would be the correct idiom to get an array (which is a suitable argument for `shift`). For a more general list, you can cast the list to an array reference and then dereference it.

```
print shift @{ [ uniq(@a) ] };
```

Comment: If we had an array reference instead, postfix dereferencing (available since v5.20), makes it more readable to get values out of references.  To get the first element, use `f()->[0]`. A slice of the result would be `f()->@[0..2]`; or the entire array as an array would be `f()->@*`. Your example would be `print uniq(@a)->[0]`

Answer (score 3):

One option could be to return an array reference:

```perl
sub uniq {
  my %seen;
  [grep !$seen{$_}++, @_];
}
```

Comment: Useful, but not applicable to my case, as in reality my function is more complex, and I cannot modify it (it is used multiple times in different part of the app). Thanks.

Comment: @Ωmega Aha, ok, yeah, that limits the possibilities of course :-) Cheers!

Comment: @Ωmega, Re "*I cannot modify it (it is used multiple times in different part of the app)*", You could make it context aware: `return wantarray ? @results : $results[0];`

Comment: @ikegami Sidenote: `wantarray` is one of my favorite perl things along with `unless` and the general _"it [the perl interpreter] doesn't do what you tell it but what it thinks you want it to do"_ (loosely quoted). :-)