# How to print nth element of Perl expression returning a list?

Tags: list, perl

I try to get the first element of

```
$object->method()
```

that is returning a list.

My first though was to try:

```
$object->method()[0]
```

But I get this error:

```
syntax error at script.pl line 42, near ")["
Execution of script.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

so I tried:

```
print ($object->method())[0];
```

but Perl 'eat' the `( )` to use with print, and still have the error.

what I need is to do:

```
print((object->method())[0]);
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: From a few days ago, see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75262096/4653379)  (so this is a dupe really but nevermind)

Comment: Difficult to find the good (key) words to this special needs.

Comment: Yes!   It's an elusive topic.  That comment of mine wasn't a complaint, just to inform :).

Comment: It's still a good question, and your answer provides good detail.  I don't think harshly about "duplicates" -- much of the time they add good things to the discussion.  (Sometimes they are indeed just pure dupes of course...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Perl, so there are many special tricks to do this.

```
print [$object->method()]->[0]
```

for another one.

Answer (score 2):

There's a special trick to do this:

```
print +($object->method())[0]
```

from `perldoc perlfunc`:

> Any function in the list below may be used either with or without
> parentheses around its arguments. (The syntax descriptions omit the
> parentheses.) If you use parentheses, the simple but occasionally
> surprising rule is this: It **looks** like a function, therefore it **is** a function, and precedence doesn't matter. Otherwise it's a list operator
> or unary operator, and precedence does matter. Whitespace between the
> function and left parenthesis doesn't count, so sometimes you need to be
> careful:
>
> ```
>     print 1+2+4;      # Prints 7.
>     print(1+2) + 4;   # Prints 3.
>     print (1+2)+4;    # Also prints 3!
>     print +(1+2)+4;   # Prints 7.
>     print ((1+2)+4);  # Prints 7.
> ```

From #perl@libera IRC:

[image: explanations]